# Как сложить значения из разных OutlinedTextField в Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Мне нужно в приложении посчитать площадь фигуры длинна и высота(если точнее, но неважно диаметр и высота цилиндра) Высота вводится в одном окне ввода, а диаметр в другом. Графику приложения скидывать смысла нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам нужна пара школьных формул?

Comment: Я не пойму в чем непонятность вопроса???  Есть два поля ввода текста. В одном вводится одно значение, а в другом - другое. Нужно умножить одно на другое))) Нужно использовать Preference DataStore? или можно проще так как сохранять значение при выходе не нужно. Если сейчас непонятен вопрос - застрелите меня.) два поля в разных Composable

Comment: Так возьмите значение из одного поля и из другого, потом делайте с ними что хотите. В чем проблема собственно?

Comment: Спасибо, сам уже решил и работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала добавим зависимости:

```
dependencies
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4")

    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.4")
```

Далее в setContent помещаем MyApp().

А вот и сама MyApp:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            // Поля ввода
            val number1 = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            val number2 = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = number1.value,
                onValueChange = { number1.value = it },
                label = { Text("Number 1") },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = Number)
            )
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = number2.value,
                onValueChange = { number2.value = it },
                label = { Text("Number 2") },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = Number)
            )
            // Кнопка умножения
            val result = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            Button(onClick = {
                val num1 = number1.value.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f
                val num2 = number2.value.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f
                val multiplyResult = num1 * num2
                result.value = multiplyResult
            })
            {
                Text("Multiply")
            }
            // Результат
            Text("Result: ${result.value}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вопрос отражает стремление разобраться; он понятен и несёт пользу - говорю как человек не просто стремящийся, а и разобравшийся. Спасибо вопрос закрыт